# Capturando a data do input type date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

tenho um

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="data">
```

NO Jquery preciso capturar essa data para depois enviar ao BD

```
var data  = $("#data").val();
```

Mas o valor só retorna 'undefined'. 
Como faço para pegar o valor de um input type date?

Comment: O `name` geralmente serve para o back-end para o front-end adicione o atribuito `id`

Comment: Com @rray mencionou, falta o id. No `jquery` o seletor com `#` serve pra encontrar em elemento por id, acrescenta um `id='data'` no seu `input` que vai funcionar

Comment: Afff... Obvio... Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao procurar por um id que não existe ele retorna undefined. Adicione o atribuito id com o respectivo nome.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="data" id="data">
```

Pode procurar elementos por nome com:

```
$("input[name='nome do input']").val()
```

`#` é usado para especificar o elemento desejado é o seletor mais especifico.

`.` Serve para especificar um ou mais elementos que utilizam determinada classe de estilo.